# How to Load Pages Quickly by delaying controls in asp.net using ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have 5 gridviews in a page. When it is opened it is taking long time to display.It is waiting until all the gridviews are  loaded.

When a page is opened, instantly I should display header and footer with "loading.." text for all 5 gridviews.Then I need to load and display each gridview one by one.. How to make this?

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the grid views on page load buy place them in an UpdatePanel. When the page loads, invoke a postback through JavaScript and then show the grid views and load their data in your page load if Page.IsPostback is true.